# not sure about port forwarding on my buffalo router to my python program

Tags: python, port-forwarding, port, flask

I have a simple python flask api running on my local computer.The api runs on my local ip address 192.168.X.X and port 5000.
My local computer is connected to a Buffalo Router.
I am able to access this api from my other device connected to same router.
But i want it to be accessibe from device outside my network basically from device on internet.
i know i need port forwarding on my router but not sure how to do it.
Also i am confused about few option available on my portforwarding interface
Like what is difference between Airstation Ip address and PPoe ip address.
I have attached my router port forwarding interface in image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kidN2.png)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will find instructions for your router in the article
[Buffalo WHR-G125 Router Open Port Instructions](https://portforward.com/buffalo/whr-g125/).

You will need to give the computer a static IP address.
If you need more info let us know if you are on Windows, Linux or the Mac.

Here are the instructions for the router page in your image:

- From the Group dropdown box select New Group.
- Create a name for this forward and put it in the Group Name box. The name is only used as a reminder and has no effect on the port forward.
- In the *Internet Side IP Address* drop-down box choose *AirStation's Internet IP Address*.
- Enable the *TCP/UDP* radio button.
- In the *Port Number and LAN Side Port* box type the port to forward (5000).
- Enter the static IP address of the computer into the *LAN Side IP Address* box.
- Click the Add button when you are all done.

[image]

Comment: Followed everything....But still it doesnt seem to work ....Just FYi after following your instruction suppose my public ip is X.X.X.X then if i punch X.X.X.X:5000 in my chrome it will work right??If it does is there any firewall or antivirus setting i need to change??

Comment: You cannot do that from inside the network, since roundabout from-to-via-Internet cannot work.

Comment: So i tried outside network from a differenct isp...it gave me X.X.X.X:5000 refused to connect...Thanks in advance...I also did a portqry which is a microsoft utility for checking querying port...It showed me [My_static_ip]:5000 listening....Thanks in advance